# not able to resolve java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, asp.net, telnet

am trying to connect to server using TelnetWrapper from apache.commons.net jar
before some days it was working file but now suddenly its giving java.net.UnknownHostException

am not able to figure out why can you please give me what could be the possible reason behind this because it was working fine before it suddenly started giving exceptions

Thanks in advance

complete exception is

```
Wrapper: java.net.UnknownHostException: cmsrv3
java.lang.Exception: Error connecting to telnet server.
    at com.honeywell.corept.util.TelnetClient.<init>(TelnetClient.java:25)
    at com.honeywell.corept.cm21.TelnetClient.<init>(TelnetClient.java:18)
    at cm21.build.CM21Build.main(Build.java:576)
```

Comment: are you able to ping to cmsrv3 from your machine?

Comment: yes am able to login from machine but from code am getting this exception not able to figure out the problem :(

Comment: Your stack trace does not look like Apache commons…

Comment: Just a suggestion.. make hosts file entry n try

Comment: am new to this am sorry i dint get you @Raghunandan Krishnamurthy

Comment: i tried all the ways but am not able to figure out the problem.... :(

Comment: go to /etc/hosts add an entry cmsrv3

Comment: in Linux /etc/hosts, windows  ..\System32\drivers\etc

Comment: @user2572003 - Got it?

Comment: HI all thaks for ur response but the problem was with my host name i have used entire path name now its working :)

Comment: but before when i used even then i dint give full name but then it worked dont know what problem is